# time line max is not defined .Please answer

Tags: javascript, html, css

<I was using timeline max it worked when i declared it for the first time but when declared it for second time it's showing error like TimelineMax is not defined even though it is working for first declaration.Declaring it for second time it is not working idk.Please answer the question as soon as possible it will be great.>

```js
function init(){
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
    const backgrounds = [
        `radial-gradient(#2B3760,#0B1023)`,
        `radial-gradient(#4E3022,#161616)`,
        `radial-gradient(#4E4342,#161616)`
    ];
    // Tracker
    let current = 0;
    let scrollSlide = 0;

    slides.forEach((slide,index) => {
        slide.addEventListener('click',function(){
            changeDots(this);
            nextSlide(index);
            scrollSlide = index;
        });
    });

    function changeDots(dot){
        slides.forEach(slide => {
            slide.classList.remove('active');
        });
        dot.classList.add('active');
    }

    function nextSlide(pageNumber){
        const nextPage = pages[pageNumber];
        const currentPage = pages[current];
        const nextLeft = nextPage.querySelector(".hero .model-left");
        const nextRight = nextPage.querySelector(".hero .model-right");
        const currentLeft = currentPage.querySelector(".hero .model-left");
        const currentRight = currentPage.querySelector(".hero .model-right");
        const nextText = nextPage.querySelector(".details");
        const portofolio = document.querySelector(".portofolio");


        const tl = new TimelineMax({
            onStart: function(){
                slides.forEach(slide => {
                    slide.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                })
            },
            onComplete : function(){ 
                slides.forEach(slide => {
                    slide.style.pointerEvents = 'all';
                })
            }
        });
        
        tl.fromTo(currentLeft, 0.3,{y : "-10%"},{y : "-100%"})
        .fromTo(currentRight, 0.3,{y : "10%"},{y : "-100%"},"-=0.2")
        .to(portofolio,0.3,{backgroundImage : backgrounds[pageNumber]})
        .fromTo(currentPage,0.3,{opacity : 1, pointerEvents : 'all'},{opacity : 0, pointerEvents : 'none'})
        .fromTo(nextPage,0.3,{opacity : 0, pointerEvents : 'none'},{opacity : 1, pointerEvents : 'all'})
        .fromTo(nextLeft,0.3,{y : "-100%"},{y : "-10%"},'-=0.6')
        .fromTo(nextRight,0.3,{y : "-100%"},{y : "10%"},'-=0.8')
        .fromTo(nextText,0.3,{opacity : 0 , y : 0}, {opacity : 1, y : 0})
        .set(nextLeft,{clearProps : 'all'})
        .set(nextRight,{clearProps : 'all'});

        current = pageNumber;
    }

    // Optional
    document.addEventListener('wheel',throttle(scrollChange,1500));
    document.addEventListener('touchmove',throttle(scrollChange,1500)); // It's gonna work on mobile too.

    function switchDots(dotNumber){
        const activeDots = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[dotNumber];
        slides.forEach(slide => {
            slide.classList.remove('active');
        })
        activeDots.classList.add('active');
    }

    function scrollChange(e){
        if(e.deltaY > 0){
            scrollSlide += 1;
        }
        else{
            scrollSlide -= 1;
        }
        if(scrollSlide > 2){
            scrollSlide = 0;
        }
        if(scrollSlide < 0){
            scrollSlide = 2;
        }
        switchDots(scrollSlide);
        nextSlide(scrollSlide);
        console.log(scrollSlide);
    }



    const hamburger = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const hamburgerLine = document.querySelectorAll('.menu line')
    const navOpen = document.querySelector('.nav-open');
    const contact = document.querySelector('.contact');
    const social = document.querySelector('.social');
    const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');

    const tl = new TimelineMax();

  hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
  });
}

function throttle(func, limit) {
    let inThrottle;
    return function() {
      const args = arguments;
      const context = this;
      if (!inThrottle) {
        func.apply(context, args);
        inThrottle = true;
        setTimeout(() => (inThrottle = false), limit);
      }
    };
  }

init();
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    box-sizing : border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family : PopLight;
    src : url(Poppins/Poppins-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family : PopRegular;
    src : url(Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf);
}

body{
    font-family : PopLight;
}

.portofolio{
    color :white;
    background : radial-gradient(rgba(43,55,96,1),rgba(11,16,35,1));
}

nav{
    min-height : 10vh;
    width : 90%;
    margin : auto;
    display : flex;
    justify-content : space-between;
    align-items : center;
    padding : 20px 0px;
}

.logo{
    font-size : 20px;
}

.page{
    min-height : 90vh;
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns : 5% 1fr 1fr 1fr 5%;
}

.chef,
.hairstylist{
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 0;
    width : 100%;
    opacity : 0;
    pointer-events : none;
}

.hero{
    overflow : hidden;
    height : 500px;
    align-self : center;
    justify-self : center;
    display : flex;
}

.hero img{
    height : 500px;
    transition : transform 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor : pointer;
}
.hero a{
    display :flex;
}

.model-right {
    transform : translate(0%,10%);
}
.model-left {
    transform : translate(0%,-10%);
}

.hero:hover .model-right {
    transform : translate(0%,0%);
}
.hero:hover .model-left {
    transform : translate(0%,0%);
}

.details {
    grid-column : 2/3;
    align-self : end;
}

.details h1{
    font-size : 64px;
    font-family : PopRegular;
}

.details h2{
    font-size : 40px;
    padding : 20px 0px;
}

.details p{
    font-size : 24px;
    padding : 20px 0px 50px 0px;
}

.pages {
    position : absolute;
    right : 5%;
    top : 50%;
    transform : translateY(-50%);
}

.pages > div{
        display : flex;
        justify-content : space-between;
        align-items : center;

}

.pages h3{
    font-size : 24px;
    padding : 30px;
}

.pages svg{
    cursor : pointer;
    opacity : 0.5;
    transform : scale(2);

}

.pages svg:hover{
    animation : dot 0.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.pages svg.active{
    opacity : 1;
}

@keyframes dot{
    0%{
        transform : scale(2);
    }
    100%{
        transform : scale(4);
    }
}

/* Photo.html */
.banner{
    height : 50vh;
    width : 100%;
    position : relative;
}

.banner img{
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    object-fit : cover;
    object-position : top;
}

.author{
    position : absolute;
    top : 70%;
    left : 50%;
    transform : translate(-50%,-70%);
    color : white;
    text-shadow : 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align : center;
}

.author h1{
    font-size : 42px;
}

.author h3{
    font-size : 32px;
    padding : 10px 0px;
}

.story,
.my-work{
    display : flex;
    justify-content : space-between;
    width : 90%;
    margin : auto;
    padding : 80px 0px;

}

.story-description,
.work-description{
    width : 50%;
}

.story-description h3,
.work-description h3{
    font-size : 36px;
    padding-bottom : 30px;
}

.story-description p,
.work-description p{
    font-size : 20px;
    padding : 20px 0px;    

}

.work-gallery{
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns : repeat(3,200px);
}

.work-gallery img{
    width : 100%;
}

@media (max-width : 1024px){
    .page{
        grid-template-columns : 5% 1fr 5%;
        grid-template-rows : 2fr 1fr;
        align-items : center;
    }
    .hero{
        grid-column : 2/3;
        height : auto;
    }
    .hero img{
        height : 500px;
    }
    .details{
        grid-row : 2/3;
        grid-column : 2/3;
        text-align : center;
    }
    .details h1{
        font-size : 48px;
    }
    .details h2{
        font-size : 35px;
    }

    .story,
    .my-work{
        flex-direction : column;
    }

    .story-description,
    .work-description{
        width : 100%;
    }

    .work-gallery{
        display : grid;
        grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px,1fr));
    }
    .profile {
        padding-top : 30px;
        text-align : center;
    }
}

@media (max-width : 768px){
    /* .page{
        grid-template-rows : 1fr 1fr;

    } */
    .hero img{
        height : 300px;
    }
    .details h1{
        font-size : 38px;
    }
    .details h2{
        font-size : 25px;
    }
}

.nav-open{
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 50vh;
    background : rgb(238, 235, 235);
    z-index : 1;
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns : 5% 1fr 1fr 5%;
    justify-items : center;
    align-items : center;
    color : black;
    text-align : center;
    transform : translateY(-100%);
}

.contact {
    grid-column : 2/3;
}`enter code here`

.nav-open h3{
    font-size : 28px;
    padding-bottom : 40px;
}

.nav-open p {
    font-size : 28px;

}

.social-links img{
    padding : 0px 20px;
}

.logo,
.menu{
    z-index : 2;
}
.menu {
    cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Dimitri Marco</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="portofolio">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <h3 class="logo">Dimitri Marco</h3>
                <svg
                class="menu" 
                 width="43"
                 height="23" 
                 viewBox="0 0 43 23" 
                 fill="none" 
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <line y1="1.5" x2="43" y2="1.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
                    <line y1="11.5" x2="28" y2="11.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
                    <line y1="21.5" x2="16" y2="21.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
                    </svg>
                <div class="nav-open">
                    <div class="contact">
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                        <p>7206589644</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social">
                        <h3>Social</h3>
                        <div class="social-links">
                            <img src="img/Twitter.svg" alt="">
                            <img src="img/Facebook.svg" alt="">
                            <img src="img/Instagram.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <section class="page photographer">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h1>Elena Morell</h1>
                        <h2>Photographer</h2>
                        <p>02/08/2018</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero">
                        <a href="photo.html">

                            <img class="model-left" src="./img/model-left.jpg" alt="model">
                            <img class="model-right" src="./img/model-right.jpg" alt="model">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="page chef">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h1>John Savos</h1>
                        <h2>Pro Chef</h2>
                        <p>02/08/2015</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero">
                        <a href="chef.html">

                            <img class="model-left" src="./img/chef-left.jpg" alt="model">
                            <img class="model-right" src="./img/chef-right.jpg" alt="model">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="page hairstylist">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h1>John Mayer</h1>
                        <h2>Pro Stylist</h2>
                        <p>02/08/2016</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero">
                        <a href="barber.html">

                            <img class="model-left" src="./img/hair-left.jpg" alt="model">
                            <img class="model-right" src="./img/hair-right.jpg" alt="model">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <div class="pages">
                    <div class="page-1">
                        <h3>01</h3>
                        <svg 
                        class="slide active"
                        width="12" 
                        height="12" 
                        viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                         fill="none" 
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <circle 
                            cx="6"
                             cy="6"
                              r="6"
                             fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page-2">
                        <h3>02</h3>
                        <svg 
                        class="slide"
                        width="12" 
                        height="12" 
                        viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                         fill="none" 
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <circle 
                            cx="6"
                             cy="6"
                              r="6"
                             fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page-3">
                        <h3>03</h3>
                        <svg 
                        class="slide"
                        width="12" 
                        height="12" 
                        viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                         fill="none" 
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="6"cy="6"r="6"fill="white"/>
                            </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </header>
    </div>
    
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="app2.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenLite.min.js"></script> -->
<script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-lPE3wjN2a7ABWHbGz7+MKBJaykyzqCbU96BJWjio86U="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-fIkQKQryItPqpaWZbtwG25Jp2p5ujqo/NwJrfqAB+Qk="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are loading your own (app.js) before the timeline JS.

From what I can see, the function init() is called in the app.js code which in turn tries to use the timeline functions but they aren't yet loaded.

I don't understand how it worked the first time as you say though.